Degrees of freedom and holonomic
I am trying to figure out some subtleties in definitions.
An omnidirectional vehicle (e.g with mecanum wheels) can move in any x or y direction as well as rotate around its z direction. It is considered holonomic. It is not disqualified based on the fact that it cannot move up and down (z) or roll around the x axis or pitch around the y axis.
A train on a train track which physically is constrained to move only forward and backwards, has one degree of freedom, +x and -x as constrained by the track. And it can move along that degree of freedom. Yet is still considered to be non-holonomic.
Please help me with the nuance?

We imagine that an omnidirectional vehicle moves in three dimensional space $[x,y,\theta]$ and can control its position and rotation at all times because it can move sideways and rotate in place.
A train also moves through three dimensional space $[x,y,\theta]$, but its movement is constrained by rails. So it has no control over its position or rotation and that is why its non-holonomic

From your paragraph one: if it moves in three dimensional space and cannot move in the z axis (up/down) why does it not make it non-h? By the same logic as your p2?

@pitosalas I imagine its because omnidirectional vehicle cannot move in z-axis by definition - it only moves on XY plane in equations, as does every ground vehicle

If you force the system into higher-dimensional space, e.g. [x,y,z,\theta] space, then omnidirectional vehicle will become non-holonomic, because there is no control over z-axis, and z will always be zero.
